# Downloading packages: warning yum

Tags: centos

after yum update

```
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centreon-stable-noarch/packages/centreon-plugins-sudoers-1.0.0-6.el7.centos.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 3fc49c1b: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CES


The GPG keys listed for the "Centreon open source software repository." repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.


 Failing package is: centreon-plugins-sudoers-1.0.0-6.el7.centos.noarch
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CES
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
rpm --import https://yum-gpg.centreon.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-CES
```

Then try again